# Continue to add items to listbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using a `listbox` to show messages and logs of my program. To add strings as the program is running, I defined a global index like this

```
function pushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global idx
%stuff
idx = idx + 1;
logs_data(idx,1) = cellstr('First string');
set(handles.logs, 'String', logs_data); %Listbox
%other stuff
```

Using global I tought that at the first iteration (when I press the button for the first time), `idx` is an empty cell that I initialize to `1`. I wrote the string and then if I push the button again, `idx` becomes `2` adding a new line below the previous one. The only problem is that when I do this, the array `logs_data` becomes a vector with empty cells except the one that currently has been added.

For example, if I push the button 5 times, I want to have `logs_data` a 5x1 array with inside the strings

```
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
```

but I get this instead

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
Iteration 5
```

How can I solve this? In an another case I could use a `for` loop increasing `idx` but since here I'm inside the button Callback I cannot use this solution.

Comment: At present I do not have access to MatLab so I can not provide you with a complete answer nevertheless, a couple of hints: according to the code you've posted, `logs_data` is neithjer a global variable nor has been declared as `persistent`; that means that each time you call the callback it is created and its previous content gets lost. Since you increment the index when you access to it, you get empty cells. Each time you call the callback, you have to get the content of the `listbox` in `logs_data` (using `get` or the `dot notation`), append the new item and assign it to the listbox.

Comment: Solved with your suggestion. Just adding a `get(handles.logs,'String')` and calling 
`logs_data(:,1) = list;`